# C# Load file from project folder

Tags: c#, file, datagridview, directory

i have a question. I have a code to load xlsx from path i put in textbox and my code looks like this:

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + safefilename.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + textBox_sheet.Text + "$]", conn); 

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Is there any way to load xlsx to datagridview from project directory? So i don't have to put path everytime even if i switch to different computer.

Comment: what exactly is the project directory? the onw where you have your `*.exe` file in the end? or are you talking about the first level of the VS-Project directory?

Comment: For example if i put my xlsx file here: \program\obj\x86\Debug\TempPE

inside project folders

Answer (score 0):

When running the application, the directory the executable is located in will be the current directory (`.\`).

When debugging the executable is located in the `bin\Debug` folder. Your project directory has the path `..\..\`:

```
string PathConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\..\" + safefilename.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

This will not work when you move the executable of your application, `..\..\` only refers to the directory two levels up in the directory hierarchy.

You'll probably want to either place the xlsx file in the same directory as the executable, as that's easier to maintain when moving the executable.

My preferred solution would be to keep the xlsx file in *AppData* in a directory for your application. You can move the file there when "installing" the application. You can then get a reference to the directory by doing this:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApplication");
```

Leaving you with this:

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApplication", safefilename.Text) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```